# jQuery Math.max return NaN after pushing / creating array

Tags: jquery, arrays, max

Good Day everyone,

I have to find the highest of values of a "pushed" array.

I am creating an array from the values of input on my web page.

```
<input name="plugin_order_data1" value="1" />
<input name="plugin_order_data2" value="2" />
<input name="plugin_order_data3" value="3" />
<input name="plugin_order_data4" value="4" />
<input name="plugin_order_data5" value="5" />
```

To build my array I used the following, the VAR is for the array and it's outside the function because the Math.max will be outside of the function

```
var $ordermaxarray = [];
($('input[name^=plugin_order_]').each(function(){
    $ordermaxarray.push($(this).val());
});
Math.max($ordermaxarray.val());
```

The Math.max returns NaN.

You can see at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpc9g9yp/) what it gives.

Do I have to "transform" the values in Numbers? What is the problem exactly because the array is only with numbers so I don't understand.

Thanks for your time!

**EDITED** Adding "definition" of var $ordermaxarray = []; instead of just var $ordermaxarray

Comment: What type is `$ordermaxarray`? From your code it looks like it's `undefined`

Comment: Am sorry... if you look on the JSFiddle the var is actually an array (with the [ ] ) I forgot to add them here, my mistake... I will edit to correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
alert(Math.max.apply(Math, order_array));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vpc9g9yp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

By the name, I think you are assuming `$ordermaxarray` to be an array, so please do the following-

```
var $ordermaxarray = [];
```

For finding the max value, you can try-

```
Math.max.apply(Math, order_array)
```

**Edit:** Removed the Array.prototype approach

Comment: "I will recommend you to define a method to it's prototype" --- It's usually considered to be not the best idea though

Comment: Please suggest me a better idea. Or it would be great if you provide useful links to read about the same.

Comment: Well, you usually just create a separated function instead. "Prefer composition over inheritance"

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the approach in the Edit to not misguide anyone on the same.